# Why do I keep getting rsync error: "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with nonzero exit code"

Tags: xcode, flutter, flutter-ios

I'm new to iOS/Flutter dev. The android portion of my project works fine but I keep getting this exit code error trying to generate an archive file for iOS distribution. I have attached a snapshot of what seems to be the issues but not sure how to resolve them.
Any assistance will be helpful. Thanks!

[image: Error image]